# removed url from Google webmaster tool, now Google don't show my website in search

Tags: web, search-engine, sitemap, google-search-console

I developed the site, and I removed the URL from Google webmaster tool which was like "http://example.com\".

I did this because Google show this in search with under construction Title, which was my previous page. When i completed the website, i removed the URL from there, and added sitemap etc to have new copy of site. Now i see in webmaster tools, that all pages are indexed, but still no success. Yahoo and Bing are showing my page when searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case try submitting a sitemap & use fetch as googlebot option and see what happens.